# Polymer 1.0 Dom-Repeat Bind Array

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0

In my try to update to Polymer 1.0 I got the following problem with Data-Binding:

My Polymer 0.5 Webapp uses a Repeat-Template to generate Checkboxes for some Categories. All `checked` values are bound to an array (`sortedCatsArray`) with the category-ids as key. Here is my first attempt to update that part to Polymer 1.0, but it doesn't work...

```
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sortedCatsArray}}" as="category">
        <paper-checkbox for category$="{{category.id}}" checked="{{filterChkboxes[category.id]}}"></paper-checkbox>
    </template>
```

As you may read in the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#path-binding), it is no longer possible to bind to Array-Properties with square-brackets (now that way: `object.property`). May anybody tell me if it's still possible to bind all generated checkbox-values in one array?

**Update #1**

As you may read in the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding), Array-Binding by index is not supported. So I tried to use that example from the docs for my case and wrote the following code. If I run this code, it seems to work as expected: the first and third checkbox is checked. But I also want the array to be changed if I manual check/uncheck a checkbox. That does not happen, only if I change the array (in the `ready`-function) the checkbox gets checked...

```
<dom-module id="my-index">
<link rel="import" type="css" href="/css/index.css">
    <template>  
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sortedCatsArray}}" as="category">
            <paper-checkbox for category$="{{category.id}}" checked="{{arrayItem(filterChkboxes.*,category.id)}}" on-change="test"></paper-checkbox>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "my-index",
    properties: {
        filterChkboxes: {
            type: Array,
            notify: true,
            observer: "filterChkboxesChanged",
            value: function(){return[true,false,true,false];}
        },
        sortedCatsArray: {
            type: Array,
            value: function(){return[{id: 0}, {id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}]},
            notify: true        
        },      
    },
    ready: function(){
        this.set('filterChkboxes.1',true);
    },
    test: function(){
        console.log(this.filterChkboxes);
    },
    observers: [
        'filterChkboxesChanged(filterChkboxes.*)'
    ],
    arrayItem: function(array, key){
        return this.get(key, array.base);
    },
    filterChkboxesChanged: function(changes){
        console.log(changes);
    },
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#expressions-in-binding-annotations) you cannot have expressions in binding annotations. Instead of `checked="{{filterChkboxes[category.id]}}"` define a [computed property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) and replace it with something like `checked="{{get_filterChkboxes(category.id)}}"` where `get_filterChkboxes` is a computed property that you should define accordingly.

Comment: Do you have a working example for that way? I thought, the `checked`-attribute is bound to the property in curly brackets. So the computed property should then return a variable in which the `checked`-state is stored. Isn't that right? But that does not work in my tries...

Comment: Yes that's right. Post a simple but also complete version of what you are trying and is not working so it's easier for someone to spot the problem. Also, take a careful look [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#attribute-bindings) and [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding).